# Chef to manage Hadoop COnfiguration / services Cluster

Tags: hadoop, automation, chef-infra, knife, mapr

I am trying to develop Chef cookbooks to Deploy and Manage Hadoop Cluster (specifically MapR).

As per my understanding Chef is a good tool to install hadoop cluster in an automated way.
But I am not sure how Chef can help to manage/change configuration of Hadoop cluster after installation and can build cluster to the state where cluster goes down completely (in case of Disaster Recovery).

Comment: Is the [hadoop cookbook](https://github.com/continuuity/hadoop_cookbook) not corresponding to your needs ?

Comment: hadoop cookbook is for Apache hadoop flavor. i am working on MapR hadoop

Comment: And this one https://github.com/boorad/mapr_cookbooks ot this one https://github.com/vmware-serengeti/serengeti-pantry/tree/master/cookbooks/mapr ? Googling around this will give you some insight on how to make your own I think.

Comment: i have seen these cookbook.....it seems that these cookbook are meant for installing hadoop...not managing lifecycle of hadoop..

Comment: https://github.com/vmware-serengeti/serengeti-pantry <= if you read carrefully, the whole configuration will be managed by chef. So any change would be done by updating attributes in the cookbook and running chef again. More precisely read [HERE](http://www.projectserengeti.org/) for the whole backend or thoose cookbooks

Comment: thanks for pointing out...but i dont see it can create mapr volumes and manage them or keep track of mapr volumes...my question is - is it feasible to maintain these kind kind of operation with Chef

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60834/discussion-between-tensibai-and-user1158351).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience with Hadoop , Chef/Puppet/Ansible or any other configuration management tool is good for installing/deploying Hadoop Distribution (Cloudera, HDP or MapR) but it is best to manage Hadoop configuration using their CM tools (like Cloudera Manager for CDH distro , Ambari for HDP and MapR CM for Mapr)